issue with sending messages automatically aiogram
i have created a telegram bot and now i want it to send a message to a user at exact time(for example, 11:10). here's how i wrote it:
async def schedule_deadline():
    global USER_NAME
    aioschedule.every().day.at('11:25').do(check_deadlines_daily)
    while True:
        print(USER_NAME)
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(10)


async def main():
    dp.include_router(router)
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.create_task(schedule_deadline())
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


but the problem is that the code doesnt even reach def check_deadlines_daily. at time which is written in  aioschedule.every().day.at('11:25') the exception occur:
future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<schedule_deadline() done, defined at C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\bot_v1\main.py:453> exception=TypeError('Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly.')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\bot_v1\main.py", line 458, in schedule_deadline
    await aioschedule.run_pending()
  File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\bot_v1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aioschedule\__init__.py", line 544, in run_pending
    await default_scheduler.run_pending()
  File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\bot_v1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aioschedule\__init__.py", line 111, in run_pending
    return await asyncio.wait(jobs, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 461, in wait
    raise TypeError("Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly.")
TypeError: Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly.

please, help me fix this problem
